# If .designer.cs generated in runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create child form in runtime from another parent form, The child contain some controls i can't detect it before runtime because it depend on data passed to parent form ? 
The child form before run have no control so `.designer.cs` have no controls option.
 So, in runtime after add controls to child form if `.designer.cs` contain properties for the generated controls? and how to copy the content of `.designer.cs` in runtime and put in in text file ?

Comment: `.designer.cs` is not modified at runtime,  the content doesn't change

Comment: @ASh there is any why to get the properties for controls that generated in runtime ?

Comment: which properties you need to get? yourControl.PropertyName will give you the value!

Comment: @Damith I want to save the control Name, Type, Location,Text

Comment: @Ahmed, yes. scan `Controls` collections recursively, starting from `winform.Controls` and save control Name, Type, Location,Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will traverse the form and get what you like from it.
If you ask for `Control`, you'll get everything on the form....

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetControls<T>(Control.ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (object ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        foreach (var item in GetControls<T>(((Control)ctrl).Controls))
        {
            yield return item;    
        } 
        if (ctrl is T)
           yield return (T)ctrl;

    }
}

foreach(var txtbox in  GetControls<TextBox>(form.Controls)
{
    txtbox.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.designer.cs` is generated by GUI visual designer (Visual Studio). It is compiled and cannot be modified at runtime.